# OAuth Implicit flow is failing, Navigation is blocked: assistant-handoff

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home, implicit-flow

We are trying out oauth implicit flow for Smart home integration with google actions. 
After successfully authenticating userid and password, redirection against redirect_uri (Sample given below) is failing with the below error (Extracted from android logcat).

"Navigation is blocked: assistant-handoff://complete/?result_code=FAILURE&result_message=Account+linking+failed", source: https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/complete (0)

Redirection URL triggered from server side:
https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/connectedghome#access_token=xxyuy12&token_type=bearer&state=CtgCQUx3MExZRXhBdlVRVHpxajBHSUFZTktVXy11V0d3a0Q4dndOZWVybndCaVpzVDR5THVJajVhWUNpMkRvSnd2eG1PTVRsRW5idjRPaUFoeHREeEY5dUFrU01kOW00SkVkTnZEX0pGNTA5R0RwTlJYcDN3Q2R5aE1XLXJXUnlzVW5iaUk3OU9YUDIya0dZWnNqeU02Ny04a3NYS0dfZXVsV1YtX19iZmpndGtheXAwdHJKYzFUOUgxT3FtR0JrNjRXSFBnc2JFRzA2cnVmSlZmNmlGbFRxek9zcGhadVJJWmhoX2tBekhsNzVvWWlSYS1FTTFPR0dOcml1ZTNORVozck9kUldwYko5TnU2aWctazAyVnhTVjNiNFVScGhZX3JOQ1BtcF9aazM3aFJvZzluSmFqWHp3U0tCYUtnMnlXb3UxMXJKWDc5aFotYThsVXlVYUR2NWV1UFoSHGFzc2lzdGFudC1oYW5kb2ZmOi8vY29tcGxldGUiPWh0dHBzOi8vb2F1dGgtcmVkaXJlY3QuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tL3IvY29ubmVjdGVkZ2hvbWUqHGNvbm5lY3RlZHNtYXJ0bGlmZUBnbWFpbC5jb20yEmNvbm5lY3RlZGdob21lX2Rldg", 
source: https://connected-safehome.in/smarthome/ui-auth/js/main.js?id=2 (109)

Kindly help us out or give us some hint on how to resolve this.
The complete flow works in OAuth playground app.
This has become a blocker.

Thanks & Warm regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use implicit flow for a smart home integration. You have to use an authorization code as described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#setup-server):

> Make sure that you have a public OAuth 2.0 server for authenticating users and apps. It should conform to the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code flow](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow).

Comment: Thanks Nick, as usual you are super quick and right on the point. I got the point that it is mentioned here in documentation, but when we try creating actions project there is an option to use implicit flow. This is confusing in my opinion. When actions project type is Smart Home Actions, then in account linking->Linking type option should give only authorization flow :). Thanks a lot for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.